# How to display array data in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am creating a survey app using React js and getting all the data from an API using the fetch method. I have an array of data and wanted to display that data inside the Html 'P' tag.

**This is the array.**

```
data : [{idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "How are you ?"}
{idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "How old are you?" }
{idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "How did you find us  ?"}
{idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "How is our service ?"}
{idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "what is your favorite food  ?"}
]
```

I used this code but it's not working.

```
<p>{this.state.data.question}</p>
```

How can I display data inside Html 'P' tag? Please help me.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map to display array data.

```
<div>
  {this.state.data.map((item) => (
    <>
      <p key={item.idsurveyquestion}>{item.question}</p>
      <p>Display what you want here</p>
    </>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: This is working fine. But I need to get that question one by one. That means I need to display a field for their answers after the question. In your code that display all the question together

Comment: it will display the questions one by one.

Comment: @Sidath this is not what you described in your question. Also where is the problem with rendering additional content for each question?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. How Can I add text field to get the answers

Comment: you can add multiple tags let me update but your response doesn't contain answer filed rt

Comment: yeah, it does not contain that. This is like a rating survey. I need to display the question one by one and then need to display rating stars for each questions

Comment: updated ans, replace 2nd `p` tag content with rating.

Comment: @Sidath are you able to fix it ? is this ans helped you?

Comment: yeah, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is there any way to display the questions one at a time?

Comment: am not quite clear, can you attach some image ? how you want to display

Comment: That means, I have 5 questions and I need to display 1st question only from the data array. and then need to get the 2nd question

Comment: in that case access questions based on index
this.state.data[0] - 1st question
this.state.data[1] - 2nd question